# how to build cado-nfs for intel xeon mic

Tags: cross-compiling, icc, xeon-phi

I have platform radhat and icc, icpc for intel xeon mic

I found that i command 'icc -mmic' as c compiler for Executing some program on intel xeon mic. (also, icpc, ... etc)

So, I use 'cmake' for compiling cado-nfs

When I compiled cado-nfs, I add variable option for cmake option and make option. Then I saw Many error...

I have searching that compiling cado-nfs for intel xeon mic. But I can't find tutorial of compiling cado-nfs for intel xeon mic or how to solve many error, ...

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: libtool: compile:  /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/bin/intel64_mic/icc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./gf2x -I. -I. -Wall -W -I/usr/local/include -I/home/cistcrypto/factorization/mic_cado/cado-nfs-2.1.1 -c gf2x.c -o gf2x.o
./gf2x/gf2x_mul2.h(43): catastrophic error: #error directive: "This code needs sse-2 support"
  #error "This code needs sse-2 support"
   ^

compilation aborted for gf2x.c (code 4)
gmake[4]: *** [gf2x.lo] error 1
gmake[3]: *** [all-recursive] error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gf2x-build] error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gf2x-build.dir/all] error 2
make: *** [all] error 2

Comment: If i commentated this line, then next line error ...

Comment: "Error: this code needs SSE-2 support" is perfectly clear. Xeon Phi X100 (aka KNC) does not support SSE-2.

Comment: @Jeff What am i doing? How can I do that compile cado-nfs without SSE-2, ..., etc some processor-oriented instruction.

sorry, This question is duplicate :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086990/how-to-compile-cado-nfs-2-1-1-for-mic-using-intel-xeon-mic .

If my problem solved, then I merge two questions to one question.

sorry to my mistake

Comment: Why don't you report the issue to the developers? Why not do a generic x86 build to start?

Comment: @Jeff I already successed to compile on generic x86. I don't think to report cado-nfs developers...

Comment: Do the generic x86 compile on MIC instead of doing whatever you do that hits SSE.

Comment: Unfortunately compiling on the coprocessor will use gcc which does not vectorize. I have downloaded the tar file for cado-nfs and will try to build it when I get a chance, although it might take a few days for me to get to it.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

Compilation and execution using cado-nfs release 2.2.0 confirmed using ICC16 for k1om.

https://github.com/mancoast/cado-nfs/tree/2.2-intel

See build scripts.